# Invalid index to scalar variable in scikit confusion matrix

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

I'm using a confusion matrix that is working just fine until I get to a specific part of my numpy arrays.

The ground truth results are stored in an array called `y_test`, while the classfiers' results are stored in `r`.

When I use the confusion matrix for the whole set of results, there are no problems.

But I want to divide the results from my experiment.
I have 3 specific classifiers' results which are stored in arrays called `c`, `b` and `t`.

Now I want to compare the results of these 3 specific classifiers against some specific indices of the overall results. For example, I want to highlight the confusion matrix for the results for classifier `C` specifically from indices 91 to 180 of the overall results.

For classifier `B` I want to see the confusion matrix of the results from indices 1 to 90.
And so on.

This is my code, below. For the first 2 confusion matrices, there are no problems. They show up fine.

```
cm_c = confusion_matrix(y_test[91:80],c[91:80])
plt.matshow(cm_c)
plt.title('Confusion matrix')
plt.colorbar()
plt.ylabel('True label')
plt.xlabel('Predicted label')
plt.show()

cm_b = confusion_matrix(y_test[1:90],b[1:90])
plt.matshow(cm_b)
plt.title('Confusion matrix')
plt.colorbar()
plt.ylabel('True label')
plt.xlabel('Predicted label')
plt.show()

cm_t = confusion_matrix(y_test[228:317,t[228:317])
plt.matshow(cm_t)
plt.title('Confusion matrix')
plt.colorbar()
plt.ylabel('True label')
plt.xlabel('Predicted label')
plt.show()
```

But for the last set of results above (using the results array from classifier `T`), I get the following error:

```
cm_t = confusion_matrix(y_test[228:317], t[228:317])
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable
```

I don't know what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your line:

```
cm_t = confusion_matrix(y_test[228:317,t[228:317])
```

you are missing a bracket. It should be:

```
cm_t = confusion_matrix(y_test[228:317],t[228:317])
```